# CR-6 SE rebooting at fixed moments in print

Tags: troubleshooting, power-supply, creality-cr-6

My printer seems to be responding poorly to some of the prints I provide it with. At a certain time, usually after at least half an hour.

For example, the print I tried today (twice) kept crashing somewhere after 52 minutes. Both times at the same spot. It would instantly reboot, ask to continue and even if I did it would crash again at the end of the backtracking.

A couple of things come to mind:

- PSU/motherboard responding poorly to some set of actions. Doing the same actions again triggers the same problem.
- Slicer producing illegal actions in some situations, causing the motherboard to panic.
- Firmware being bugged, responding poorly in some edge cases.

Other prints work fine.

How would I go about finding what's causing the reboots?
As a workaround, I'd accept a method of finding out whether a specific print would have this behaviour (incl. looking at the resulting gcode if that helps), without having to waste an hour (or more) of time and material each time.

System:

- CR-6 SE.
- Recent [Community Firmware](https://github.com/CR6Community/Marlin/tree/v2.0.7.3-cr6-community-release-6).
- Stock parts except for the cold-end extruder, that's switched out for an all-metal dual-gear.
- Creality Slicer 4.8.2.

*Note:* I feel obligated to mention the printer is on an unearthed power socket (old building, only ground floor has a couple of earthed sockets). This might make parts of the system less forgiving than it would otherwise, but I'm not sure about that. Internal wiring of the printer (for as much as it's accessible) seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is the behaviour of files that get corrupted. This has very little to do with the slicer and everything with how some SD cards are just intent on getting themselves a bad name.

In this case, the file was corrupted enough not to be readable on the machine that put the data on there. If the file can't be opened and made look readable by a normal text editor, it's probably corrupted and not worth trying to print. A quick scroll-through to check it's all there might be a good idea as well.